# Erro em injeção de dependências dos módulos em angular

Tags: angularjs, injeção-de-dependência, angularjs-services, angularjs-factorys

tenho o módulo da minha aplicação:

```
angular.module('app', ['app.controllers','app.routes','app.services']);
```

tenho o meu módulo de services:

```
angular.app('app.services', [])
    .factory('usuarioService', ['$rootScope', 'renderService',
        function($rootScope, renderService){
            // logica do factory
    }]);

angular.module('app.services', [])
    .factory('renderService', ['$http',
        function($http){
            // logica do factory
    }]);
```

e tenho meu controller:

```
angular.module('app.controllers', ['app.services'])
    .controller('meuCtrl',
        ['$scope','$rootScope','usuarioService','renderservice',
            function($scope, $rootScope, usuarioService, renderService){
               // logica do controller
    }]);
```

Mas ao rodar a aplicação, recebo erro de injeção de dependencias:

```
Unknown provider: usuarioServiceProvider <- usuarioService <- meuCtrl
```

Não entendo o que pode estar acontecendo, já que faço a injeção em cada local apropriado.

a menos que eu esteja fazendo estas injeções erradas.

PS.: Todos os arquivos .JS estão sendo carregado no index.html, nenhum foi esquecido.

Comment: Poste o seu HTML também.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está definindo o módulo app.services duas vezes.

Quando você passa o array de dependências, o angular cria um módulo novo.

Sem o array, ele pega um módulo já existente.
Tente remover o [] na segunda definição.

```
angular.module('app.services')
.factory('renderService', ['$http',
    function($http){
        // logica do factory
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Da forma que você declarou os services, o segundo está sobrescrevendo o primeiro, pois quando se usa o injetor de dependências "[]" dentro do module, o angular cria um modulo novo.

Sugiro você tentar dessa forma.

```
angular.module('app.services',[]);

var appServices = angular.module('app.services');

appServices.factory('usuarioService', ['$rootScope', 'renderService',
        function($rootScope, renderService){
            // logica do factory
    }]);

appServices.factory('renderService', ['$http', function($http){
            // logica do factory
    }]);
```